# Cannot get the right result when iterating and applying a conditional statement in a DataFrame's column

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I have a dataframe frame in which I need to iterate through one of the columns and apply certain conditional statements for using one or the other set of equations.

I've written the code below. However, I'm not getting the right result. In the code, the input_data variable is checked for positive values, but the condition is not met when encountering a negative value and always applies the equations for the case of positive values.

thanks in advance for any advice on this

```
import pandas as pd
x=[-1,1]
y=[2,3]

df=pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
print(df)

   x  y
0 -1  2
1  1  3

input_data=df['x']

for i in range(len(input_data)):
    
if input_data[i]>0:
    df['z']=input_data[i]+1
    df['z2']=df['z']+1
    df['z3']=1
else:
    df['z']=input_data[i]-1
    df['z2']=df['z']-1
    df['z3']=0
        
print(df)
   x  y  z  z2  z3
0 -1  2  2   3   1
1  1  3  2   3   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pandas, loops are generally implemented with [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
df[['z','z2','z3']] = df.apply(
    lambda row: [row.x+1, row.x+2, 1] if row.x > 0 else [row.x-1, row.x-2, 0],
    result_type='expand',
    axis=1)

#    x  y    z   z2   z3
# 0 -1  2 -2.0 -3.0  0.0
# 1  1  3  2.0  3.0  1.0
```

Or you can use the vectorized [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```py
df['z'] = np.where(df.x > 0, df.x + 1, df.x - 1)
df['z2'] = np.where(df.x > 0, df.z + 1, df.z - 1)
df['z3'] = df.x.gt(0).astype(int)

#    x  y  z  z2  z3
# 0 -1  2 -2  -3   0
# 1  1  3  2   3   1
```

---

As for the `for` loop implementation, the issue was due to the assignment statements.

For example `df['z3'] = 1` sets the the whole `z3` column to `1` (not just any particular row of `z3` but the whole column). Similarly `df['z3'] = 0` sets the whole column to 0. This applies to all those assignment statements.

So then because the last `x` value is positive, the final iteration sets all the `z` columns to the positive result.

Comment: thank you @tdy. It works now. Any thoughts of what might be wrong with the for loop I tried?

Comment: @Pablo sure, i updated the answer with an explanation, let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: thank you for that detailed explanation! I understand now why I was getting the results the way I did. The solutions you proposed are more efficient. Just for curiosity, would there be a way to rewrite the for loop to get the correct answer?

Comment: @Pablo you would have to index each cell location, e.g.: `df.loc[i, 'z2'] = df.loc[i, 'z'] + 1`